# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в предложении, где есть однородные слова, но "и" одна? Предложение ниже

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены

Предложение: 
Документы MS Office, файлы PDF, и изображения из входящей клиентской почты будут автоматически сохранены в каталоге.

Вопрос: нужна ли запятая перед "и изображения" (после файлы PDF)?

Answer (score 1):

**Документы MS Office, файлы PDF и изображения из входящей клиентской почты будут автоматически сохранены в каталоге.**

Это простое предложение, в котором однородные подлежащие (*документы*, *файлы* и *изображения*) соединены одиночным союзом **и**. Запятая перед ним не требуется.

Однородными называются члены предложения, отвечающие на один и тот же вопрос, относящиеся к одному и тому же члену предложения и выполняющие одинаковую синтаксическую функцию (т. е. занимающие позицию одного члена предложения).

[Запятая перед союзом «И»](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)
[Однородные члены, соединенные союзами](http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/1946d260-e1a1-4308-8126-72b39aaea09a/punc11.htm)